# Error getting JSON data in AsyncTask with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get `JSON` data from an `URL` with I have the following error:

```
Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Until now I used `HttpClient` but with API23 it is deprecated, could someone help me?

This is what I have now:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri){

    String responseString = "...";

    URL url ;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(responseString);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        assert urlConnection != null;
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return responseString;

}
```

This is what I had:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackGround(String...uri){
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI apiCall = new URI("...");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(apiCall);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "some sort of problem encountered", e);
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: This is not at all an attempt to answer your question, but have you considered using some library? I recommend **Retrofit**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `GET` as,

```
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }
```

To convert your json String to an actual object you can use `Gson`.
 Or you can forget about this `HttpURLConnection` apprach and use `Retrofit` library to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Is there a way to "convert" my ex code to a non-deprecated one so that I can use in doInBackground method?

Comment: You can ignore it, but no, you should use the new API, You can suppress the deprecated warnings in java. But that is not a solution. What is the issue of using this new API, there are lot of examples and tutorials you can find in the interent

Answer (score 0):

You don't post the code that causes the error `Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`. However, because your async task in the first snippet (using `HttpURLConnection`) returns **responseString** which is a url address (started with "http://" for example), of course, it is not a valid JSONObject.